# Convert a string separate by . and +

Tags: r, string

I would like to convert this:

`v_in <- 'A+B+C.E+F.G'`

into this:

`v_out <- 'A.E.G+A.F.G+B.E.G+B.F.G+C.E.G+C.F.G'`

using R.
Any ideas?

Comment: What title would you give your question? Could you further elaborate the logic used?

Comment: I second @NelsonGon's request for more details. It's not clear how you get from `v_in` to `v_out`. What are the rules?

Comment: another example: FRA+DEU.VAR1+VAR2.A into FRA.VAR1.A+FRA.VAR2.A+DEU.VAR.A+DEU.VAR2.A

Comment: I found by myself, thanks all

Comment: Can you please have a look at the answers below and accept the one you want so we can consider this closed? You should also add your solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea, but It might be a bit overfitted on your example. However, I can not generalize it due to lack of information regarding the rules.

```
l1 <- strsplit(strsplit(v_in, '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]][-1], '+', fixed = TRUE)
i2 <- c(outer(l1[[1]], l1[[2]], function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = '.')))
i3 <- gsub('\\..*', '', strsplit(v_in, '+', fixed = TRUE)[[1]])

paste(t(outer(i3[-length(i3)], i2, function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = '.'))), collapse = '+')
#[1] "A.E.G+A.F.G+B.E.G+B.F.G+C.E.G+C.F.G"
```

Answer (score 2):

Step by step so it is more clear, you can use the following:

```
v_in2=strsplit(v_in,"\\.")[[1]]                        # split by points
v_in3=sapply(v_in2,function(x) strsplit(x,"\\+")[[1]]) # split each by +
v_in4=expand.grid(v_in3)                               # combine all variables of each group
v_in5=do.call(paste,v_in4)                             # paste combinations
v_out=paste(gsub(" ","\\.",v_in5),collapse="+")        # change spaces for . and paste all together by +
> v_out
[1] "A.E.G+B.E.G+C.E.G+A.F.G+B.F.G+C.F.G"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (my solution use 2 for and is not so elegant thant yours)

Answer (score 2):

One of the occasions when I think a loop works well:

```
v_out <- v_in        
for(spl in c(".","+")) {
    v_out <- unlist(lapply(v_out, strsplit, spl, fixed=TRUE),rec=FALSE)
}
eg <- expand.grid(v_out)
eg <- eg[do.call(order,eg),]
paste(do.call(paste, c(eg,sep=".")),collapse="+")
#[1] "A.E.G+A.F.G+B.E.G+B.F.G+C.E.G+C.F.G"
```

And for anyone still waiting for an explanation of the pattern, this might help:

```
@ @ @ : : $
A+B+C.E+F.G
@     :   $   A.E.G
@       : $   A.F.G
  @   :   $   B.E.G
  @     : $   B.F.G
    @ :   $   C.E.G
    @   : $   C.F.G
```